# Trouble Installing npm on Mac

Tags: macos, node.js

I can't seem to get npm working on os x mountain lion with the latest version of node (0.8.11). Either building from source, or using the installer, I get a command not found when trying to run npm. I checked /usr/local/bin and npm is present, here's an ln -l

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  38 Oct  2 16:33 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

Following to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin shows

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 24561  staff   136 Oct  2 16:33 node-gyp-bin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff   274 Sep 27 12:39 npm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff  2247 Sep 27 12:39 npm-cli.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root   staff   209 Sep 27 12:39 npm.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff   504 Sep 27 12:39 read-package-json.js
```

When running 'make install' from source, I get the following error

```
symlinking ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js -> /usr/local/bin/npm
updating shebang of /usr/local/bin/npm to /usr/local/bin/node
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tools/install.py", line 225, in <module>
run(sys.argv[:])
File "tools/install.py", line 220, in run
if cmd == 'install': return files(install)
File "tools/install.py", line 203, in files
if 'true' == variables.get('node_install_npm'): npm_files(action)
File "tools/install.py", line 166, in npm_files
update_shebang(link_path, shebang)
File "tools/install.py", line 133, in update_shebang
s = open(path, 'r').read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/npm'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

My path is the following:

```
bash:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

The installer runs smoothly with no errors, but I still won't execute npm. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not on Mountain Lion, but MacPorts works fine for me. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I actually ended up using MacPorts and it worked perfectly

Comment: Note that '/usr/local/bin/npm' is a JavaScript script that tries to run using 'node' (which it finds using standard 'shebang' practise: /usr/bin/env node). Do you have 'node' in your PATH somewhere... I assume it's in /usr/local/bin, but perhaps not?

Answer (score 0):

This is now a few months old, however, node.js is updated to 0.8.22, and has corrected this issue.

The preferred method is to download the Mac OSX installer package if you do not want to install Macports for this one program.